# ajax submit to WebAPI controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm not sure of the best way to accomplish my goal.  Looking for insight.  I'm familiar with WebAPI services consumed through WPF and Silverlight but this is my first run at ASP and MVC.

I am building a site to verify contents of a shipment against an electronic manifest (EDI 856).  I have a page that displays the shipping data and I need the users to scan each item barcode in the container.  I would then like to pass that barcode to a service, verify the item belongs in that shipment and then update the page to show as much.

My plan was to have a single text box into which the user could scan/type the barcode and then submit that data to a WebAPI service which would verify the information and then probably use SignalR to send a message back to the page and update a grid with the item data.

If this is a decent way to go, I'm just not quite sure how to use ajax to call the WebAPI endpoint and provide the data I need.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: But apparently like almost all forums, there are those who like to make completely useless replies that serve no purpose except to "correct" a poster.

Comment: Say "educate" and you'll be correct. Take some time to learn about the site you're using. [so] is different in many ways. Community moderation is one of the most important differences.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise against using SignalR in this situtation. What you need, judging from your description, is the most basic use case of submitting an ajax request and receiving a response.

You are not designing a system where you need the server to initiate communication with the browser or anything like that, where sockets (and SignalR as an abstraction over sockets with fallbacks to less suitable protocols) is a huge overkill.

Don't worry, your use case is rather simple.

It's a little out of scope to describe how to setup a WebApi project, how to configure routing, action names, etc. Simple google searches will surely provide ample quality tutorials on getting started.

I'll just try to explain what the general idea is, with some code samples, to get you thinking in the right direction.

You need to create an ApiController.
The simplest version of that Controller will probably look something like this:

```
public class ShipmentVerificationController : ApiController
{
    //this is the response object you will be sending back to the client website
    public class VerificationResult
    {
        public bool Valid;
    }

    public VerificationResult GetIsItemValid(string BarCode)
    {
        bool itemIsValid;
        // Implement checks against the BarCode string here
        itemIsValid = true;
        return new VerificationResult { Valid = itemIsValid };
    }
}
```

Note that the inner class represents the response you will be sending back. It should be properly filled out with additional info if needed and probably put into a separate .cs file in the "Models" folder or where ever you see fit.

I have declared it inside the controller for demonstration purposes only

Once you have a WebApi service deployed, it's really easy to send it data from your website and receive the feedback.
To simplify Ajax requests, jQuery is often used.

Once the user inputs the barcode into a textbox, you can hook up an event to check for return key being pressed (most barcode scanners send the return key command after they input the barcode data) and then write something along the lines of:

```
var barcode = $("#input-field").val();

$.getJSON( "<url_to_your_webapi_service>/api/ShipmentVerification/GetIsItemValid/" + barcode, function( data ) {
if (data.Valid) {
// great, highlight the item as valid
}
else {
//better indicate an error with the scanned item
}

});
```

Please note that for simplicity I have not included any error handling, url parameter encoding, and most importantly, zero authorization.
Authorization is very important if you deploy the web service to the open web but still do not want anyone to be able to call it.

You will have to research these topics yourself, but I hope I have presented you the core concepts and logic behind a simple service such as this, so you have a base to start with.

If you come up with specific problems and questions post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a more simple way to do this.  I nixed the idea of using a WebAPI endpoint and just went with a normal controller.  I used ajax to prevent the page from refreshing with the new view, since that view is actually just json data with my return values in it.